# Save dates in UTC timezone

Tags: android, json, realm

I'm receiving a JSON from my server with dates in UTC timezone

```
"startDate": "2016-05-24T22:30:00.000Z",
```

but when I call `Realm.createOrUpdateObjectFromJson`, my dates are changed  to its equivalent on the device current time zone.

Is there any preference I can set in realm so my dates get parsed as UTC dates?

## EDIT

This is part of the json I'm getting from my server.

[image: This is part of the json I'm getting from my server.]

This is how it's getting save in my realm file.

[image: This is how it's getting save in my realm file.]

Comment: How are you testing that? The `toString()` method of a Date will use the default timezone which might make it look wrong?

Comment: No, I'm getting the realm file from my device and that's the way it's shown in the realm browser.

Comment: @christian-melchior I updated my question with some images that might be helpful. As I mention I'm not doing anything else with the json, I only used it to call `Realm.createOrUpdateObjectFromJson`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guys at Realm Browser told me that dates in Realm don't contain any timezone data. So this is the browser rendering a timestamp in your timezone.

Here's the github issue in the Realm Browser repo:
https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/issues/169